# What is the difference between SQL Server 2012 SP4 vs SP3 with CU-10?

Tags: sql-server-2012, patching

Sorry, may be very stupid question but what is the difference between SQL Server 2012 SP4 and SQL Server 2012 SP3 + CU-10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2012 SP4 contains all the same fixes as 2012 SP3 CU #10, and was basically just a rollup to release a final service pack. The only differences are going to be:

- build number will be higher
- longer end of life
- potentially better chance of servicing for a security issue in the future
- easier slipstreaming

Personally I would go with 2012 SP4.

Comment: Great, just what I suspected, without the details. I also want to go SP4, but I need to convince my Boss :)